# How to validate child value in nested json

Tags: json, command-line, jq

This is the json respond body:

```
{
  "studentName": "good student",
  "age": "18",
  "address": "street 123",
  "courses": {
    "math": {
      "description": "how to calculate",
      "enrollment": "enrolled",
      "status": {
        "result": "OK"
      }
    },
    "english": {
      "description": "abc",
      "enrollment": "not-enrolled",
      "status": {
        "result": "OK"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to validate the "enrollment" value, for example, I want to get the output in the format:

```
math : enrolled
english : not-enrolled
```

wondering how to do this with jq command, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what your asking

Comment: @newGuy, For example, jq command `jq '.courses'` will give the result: `{
  "math": {
    "description": "how to calculate",
    "enrollment": "enrolled",
    "status": {
      "result": "OK"
    }
  },
  "english": {
    "description": "abc",
    "enrollment": "not-enrolled",
    "status": {
      "result": "OK"
    }
  }
}`  I am trying to get the math enrollment status and the english enrollment status in the format `math : enrolled
english : not-enrolled`

Comment: I believe @Jeff has the right idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "validate." But to simply get the `"course"` and it's current `"enrollment"` status, you could do this:

```
.courses | to_entries[] | "\(.key) : \(.value.enrollment)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If "validate" means checking that the values are all as expected, then you could use a filter along these lines:

```
.courses
| with_entries( select( .value.enrollment as $e
                | ["enrolled", "not-enrolled"] | index($e) | not) )
```

That is, select the courses for which the "enrollment" is NOT in the list of acceptable values.  (Here, "X | not" has the effect of negating X.)

Running this against your data augmented with a course for which the "enrollment" is invalid yields that course:

```
{
  "french": {
    "description": "abc",
    "enrollment": "non",
    "status": {
      "result": "OK"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @peak, this is exactly what I meant.